# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1

Tags: java, android, json, jsonserializer, json-serializable

I am trying to serialize the bellow JSON data in java

```
  [{
    "clear": "0",
    "default": ["123","234"],
    "mandatory": "1",
    "visible": "1"
}]
```

my serializer Class looks like bellow,

```
public class HandleConfig{
@SerializedName("visible")
private  int visible;
@SerializedName("clear")
private  int clear;
@SerializedName("mandatory")
private int mandatory;
@SerializedName("default")
private JSONArray def;

// getter and setter methods here...
```

}

//call to the serializer

```
Gson gson1 = new Gson();
Type collectionType1 = new TypeToken<List<HandleConfig>>(){}.getType();
List<HandleConfig> handleConfigurations = gson1.fromJson(object.toString(), collectionType1);
```

// the Error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 267 path $[0].default
```

I have referred various stack Overflow answers.. and come to know the reason behind this is serializer is expecting the "default" to be the bellow format

```
 "default":[{ "id":123},{"id":124}]
```

but now my question is how to serialize **"defalut":["123","1234"]**  to JSON Array without producing any errors,

thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this for that parsing :

`List<String> def` instead of  `JSONArray def`